# Prove that $4x^{n} + (x+1)^{2} = y^2$ doesn't have positive integer solutions for $n \ge 3$

Tags: number-theory

Equation is: $4x^{n} + (x+1)^{2} = y^2$
Task is to prove:

a) for $n = 1$ there are no solutions

b) for $n = 2$ there is infinite number of solutions

c) for $n \ge 3$ there are no solutions

I have proved $a$ and $b$, but have no idea about $c$. There is nothing common with $a$ and $b$

Comment: How about $x=0, y=\pm 1$? Or $n=2014, x=-1, y=\pm 2$? Is there a restriction on $x, y$ to be positive?

Comment: Yes, they are positive

Comment: *boy, that escalated quickly...*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $x, y$ positive and $n \geq 3$, note $y \equiv x+1 \pmod{2}$ so

$$4x^n=y^2-(x+1)^2=(y-(x+1))(y+(x+1))$$
$$x^n=\frac{y-(x+1)}{2}\frac{y+(x+1)}{2}$$

Now if $\exists$ prime $p$ with $p \mid \frac{y-(x+1)}{2}$ and $p \mid \frac{y+(x+1)}{2}$, then $p \mid x^n$ so $p \mid x$. Also $p \mid \frac{y+(x+1)}{2}-\frac{y-(x+1)}{2}=(x+1)$, a contradiction.

Thus $\gcd(\frac{y-(x+1)}{2}, \frac{y+(x+1)}{2})=1$, so both $\frac{y-(x+1)}{2}$ and $\frac{y+(x+1)}{2}$ are (positive) $n$th powers. We may thus write $$\frac{y-(x+1)}{2}=\alpha^n, \frac{y+(x+1)}{2}=\beta^n, x=\alpha\beta$$ for some positive integers $\alpha, \beta$.

Then $\alpha\beta+1=x+1=\frac{y+(x+1)}{2}-\frac{y+(x+1)}{2}=\beta^n-\alpha^n$.

Clearly we require $\beta>\alpha$. Write $\beta=\alpha+k$, $k$ a positive integer. Then

$$\alpha^2+k\alpha+1=\alpha\beta+1=\beta^n-\alpha^n=(\alpha+k)^n-\alpha^n \geq nk\alpha^{n-1} \geq 3k\alpha^2$$

However

$$3k\alpha^2-(\alpha^2+k\alpha+1)=(k-1)\alpha^2+k\alpha(\alpha-1)+(k\alpha^2-1) \geq 0$$

so equality holds and we must have

$$(k-1)\alpha^2=k\alpha(\alpha-1)=(k\alpha^2-1)=0$$

i.e. $k=\alpha=1$, i.e. $\alpha=1, \beta=2$. But then $3=\alpha\beta+1=\beta^n-\alpha^n=2^n-1$, so $n=2$, a contradiction.

Comment: Man you awesome!!! Thank you very much!

Comment: Ps change sign after "however"