Find $n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ such that there exists $x\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ where $4x^n+(x+2)^2$ is a perfect square
Find $n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ such that there exists $x\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ where $4x^n+(x+2)^2$ is a perfect square.
I know and can prove that $n=1$ is not a solution. However, $n=2$ works (using $x=4,30,\dots$), but for $n\ge 3$, I tried to let
$$4x^n+(x+2)^2=k^2$$
for $k\in\mathbb{Z}^+$, then
$$4x^n=(k-x-2)(k+x+2)$$
And I didn't get any further.
Question: Does there exist $n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$, $n\ge 3$ such that there exists $x\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ where $4x^n+(x+2)^2$ is a perfect square? If yes, how many are there?

What is the context for this question?  If it is homework for an introductory class, then one would expect it to have a straight forward solution using standard techniques.  If it is just a question that you came up with while playing with numbers, then there'd be no reason to expect a simple result.

The pair $(n,x)=(5,2)$ works

for even $n$, it probably is bounded between the squares of $2x^{n/2}$ and $2x^{n/2}+1$ for large enough $x$ and $n\geq 4.$ Odd case is probably difficult.

@lulu it's homework for district level excellent student math class

Similar question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/820699/prove-that-4xn-x12-y2-doesnt-have-positive-integer-solutions-fo?noredirect=1.

If $4x^n+(x+2)^2=y^2$ and $n$ is even, then $(2x^{n/2}, x+2, y)$ would be a Pythagorean triple.

Maybe consider a diophantine tag.  Don't know but quadratic residues might also have applicability.

A WAY FORWARD
Your initial factorisation was a good idea. You can continue as follows.
First prove that no odd prime can be a factor of both $k-x-2$ and $k+x+2$.
Then you can write  $$k+x+2=2^Aa^n $$$$k-x-2=2^Bb^n $$ where $a$ and $b$ are odd and coprime.
Then $$4x^n=2^{A+B}a^nb^n$$ $$2(x+2)=2^Aa^n-2^Bb^n$$
Then consider what happens when $x$ is odd, singly even, divisible by 4.
